# ComboBox - bind selected value

Tags: wpf, binding, enums

I want to bind  the combobox's selected value to the bounded object  property, and also set the selected index of every combobox to 0.
The problem is that only first combo shows the selected item.

```
public enum SubEnum1
{       
   Apple=1,
   Banana=2,
   Pear=3
}    

public enum FullEnum
{       
   Apple=1,
   Banana=2,
   Pear=3,

   Cucumber=4,
   Tomato=5,
   Onion=6
}
```

Im XAML window i have some data control (list) where is a datatemplate that has a combobox.
comboboxes are bounded to SubEnum1.

The data-control is bounded to an object-collection:

```
List<MyObject> collection = new List<MyObject>()
//collection.Add...

mylist.ItemsSource = collection;

public class MyObject
{
  public FullEnum TheSelectedEnum {get;set;}
  ....
  //other properties
}



public class EnumConverter2 : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {

            return value;

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null)
                return (FullEnum)value;

            else return "";

        }
    }
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Enum1"
                    MethodName="GetValues" 
                    ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type TypeName="local:SubEnum1" />
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>

<ListBox Height="261" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="mylist" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="278">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel>              
              <ComboBox Height="23" Width="90"                                
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Enum1}}"  
                        SelectedValue="{Binding Path=TheSelectedEnum, Converter={StaticResource enumConverter}}"
                        SelectedIndex="0"/> 
          </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>     

</ListBox>
```

[image: screen]
(If I expand other comboboxes I see the values)

**Update to post:**

Maybe I can somehow else pass the selected value to the binded object?

Comment: BTW, you don't need to add the number after every enum value - each value is automatically one greater than the last.
Sure, set your first value to 1 or whatever you like, but all the rest will automatically follow.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this and solve your problem:

```
public enum SubEnum1 
{           
    None=0,     
    Apple=1,    
    Banana=2,    
    Pear=3 
}
```

Then use FallbackValue:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" Width="90"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Enum1}}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=TheSelectedEnum, FallbackValue=0}" />
```

Comment: But adding None=0, to SubEnum1  will add extra item to the combobox. I don't need it. IF there is an error or Fail i want to select the first item and bind to the object (with the needed cast). I tired to use Converter but it didn't work also